# evaluateJavaScript in a WKWebView's iframe?

Tags: javascript, ios, wkwebview

I have successfully set up a WKWebView ScriptMessageHandler to receive messages from inside my webview. I'm then using `evaluateJavaScript` to send responses back into the webview. This works fine when everything is executed on the main frame of the view.

However, when I try to do this inside an iFrame I run into difficulties. I still receive the message in the message handler (complete with `WKFrameInfo` to tell me where it came from) but I can't find any way to run `evalateJavaScript` targeting that frame. I *could* use a `window.frames` hack in my evaluated JavaScript, but if the iFrame is of a different origin than the parent frame then I'm going to run into cross-domain errors.

Is there any way to identify a frame inside WKWebview, and evaluate JS on it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Three years later: iOS 14 will support this.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkwebview/3656442-evaluatejavascript